# How to uniquely identify a client in a web (PHP) application

Tags: php, security, web

We've been developing a web application (PHP, using the Yii PHP framework) that is going to be used for data entry. The clients will be users from both the LAN and WAN (many of the remote clients will be behind a proxy, reaching our network using one IP address with NAT). What we basically want is to guarantee the validity of data in the way that no malicious user alters it.

Is there a way to programmatically identify each client in a unique way, so that I can guarantee (at least at some good percent) that no malicious remote user will connect? We were thinking of gathering the MAC addresses of all remote users and using a (non-web) client that generates a hash string that the user will input in the web application and then proceed if this authentication scheme passes. As I said, using other non-web applications for the remote client is an option.

Is such a solution as the one I describe above viable? Should we see other solutions, like maybe a VPN?

Comment: If you relax the question a bit, so that the title is the question, then the answer is that it cannot be done. There is currently no mechanism to identify a client connection. In PHP, "$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']" used to work, but when a VPN proxies many clients, it now fails. We need a new standard if we are ever to support stateful connections, such as for completing a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A VPN is a typical solution to the problem of locking out everyone except those you've explicitly given access --- basically you're rejecting all connections to the site that aren't authenticated in your local network or vpn. That way you dont have to write any funky logic for your actual web application.

I think this is an ideal solution because it allows the application to be maintainable in the future when other developers step in... furthermore it will require less of your developers and will ultimately keep costs down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess we will need to look at a solution like OpenVPN. How much difficult is such a setup for the end user?

Comment: Good question! the solution to that is probably waiting for you in http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3):

Normal user authentication is generally OK, but if you have higher security needs you can provide clients X.509 certificates to install in their browser. VPN is of course an option but you just move authentication problem from website to network vpn.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a quick how to for such a solution?

Comment: i found this very complete for your situation: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are the SSH-Key pairs:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

There are much more ressources on this, the theory in brief:
Each client creates a pair of unique keys, a private and public one. The public goes onto your server, the private stays with him. Then the client uses the key to authenticate. The server calculates a valid public key from it and checks if you have such a key in your system. If a pair is found - authentication was successful. (I never used this so far for Web authentification)

Additionally you could use OTP (One Time Password) technology. Since it is normally bound on per-account basis it will be very secure:
https://github.com/lelag/otphp